# php ini setting not reflecting after upgrading apache2 to mpm_event in ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, apache2-module

I have update my apache2 from mpm_prefork to mpm_event with php5_fpm. After updating this my php.ini in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini still configuration not work. I have set max_execution_time to 60 but it is not work.

My configuration is

**php :** PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22 (fpm-fcgi)

**Server OS :** Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit)

**apache2 version :** Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

**Loaded Configuration File** : /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

Comment: Call phpinfo, and check what php.ini is actually used.

Comment: phpinfo show  /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

Comment: check to see if your php.ini has duplicates, the latter will override the former.

Also restart the server. Changes to php.ini take effect after restart

Comment: no there is no duplicate file. Also I have restart my server

Answer (score 2):

You need to reload php-fpm in order for php.ini changes to take effect. Look for something like

```
/etc/init.d/php-fpm
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm
```

and run the reload command like

```
sudo /etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm reload
```

You may not require to reload or restart Apache for php.ini changes anymore.

Comment: You are the hero!